# store list of up to 10000 records for lookup from apex code

Tags: apex, limits, custom-metadata, data-storage, data-set

for an automated pricing method in apex I would need to access a list with 10000 zip codes, with each zip code having a specific value assigned. What is the best approach to store and access?
Do you consider a custom metadata object would be sufficient ?
pseudo-code: getBIP(zipCode){}

Comment: Custom Metadata Types are good for storing information that doesn't change very often, because any changes need to be made in a sandbox or other org and then deployed to production like code. Depending on who will be maintaining the pricing values, it might be more useful to store in an sObject table or Custom Setting. Of course, these have disadvantages as well. The apex code used to access the table is not that different for each of these.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy!